# Cannot mount nfsv4 exports

Tags: linux, centos, mount, nfs, kerberos

i tried to setup nfsv4 server and client on centos7.3,both server(ark-centos7-ker ),client(ark-centos-smb4) are joined to AD domain by realm command,AD domain users could log in to centos server
run kinit could get kerberos tickets,but mount nfsv4 export from client failed see following

```
[arkadmin@QA.ARKIVIO.COM@ark-centos-smb4 ~]$ sudo mount -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5 ark-centos7-ker.qa.arkivio.com:/export/nfs1 /nfs4-mnt-dir
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting ark-centos7-ker.qa.arkivio.com:/export/nfs1
```

server side nfsv4 exports setting

```
[root@ark-centos7-ker ~]# exportfs -v
/export/nfs1    <world>(rw,wdelay,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p,rw,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/export/nfs2    <world>(rw,wdelay,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=sys:krb5:krb5i:krb5p,rw,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

please give some suggestion,i know it's complicated in Kerberos,nfsv4 settings
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out,re-join domain by realm command for both client,server

```
realm join --user=admin@QA.ARKIVIO.COM --user-principal=nfs/ark-centos-smb4.qa.arkivio.com@QA.ARKIVIO.COM QA.ARKIVIO.COM
```

it will create relevant nfs/* credentials for client,server then mount nfsv4 exports with sec=krb5 option succeeded